# Linking FreeImage as a static library in VS2010?

Tags: c++, image, freeimage

I need a image library and I've been looking into FreeImage, http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/.
I want to link it statically with my application.

I have tried downloading the binaries and link it with, but I get 2019 linker errors when I try to call their functions, even though I am positive I linked it correct.

So then I tried to download their source, converted their "FreeImageLib.2008" to VS2010 and built it. It builds just fine on its own, but I still have the same problem when linking against it, my application that uses it still complaints about linker errors.

I also set all the project configuration to match my other projects, so there is no conflict with /MDd or /MTd, etc..

I did some digging in their source and there are macros like "FREEIMAGE_LIB" which suggests it should be defined when building a static library, and it IS defined, yet still it dosn't work.

I've googled around and cannot find any solid answers to this issue. The answer on [Getting FreeImage to work with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225890/getting-freeimage-to-work-with-visual-studio-2010) makes no difference; I already defined the macro either before including the header or as a preprocessor argument but it dosnt work.

Is this library not meant to be used as a static library, or what could possibly be the issue?
Has anyone been able to link FreeImage statically on VS2010+?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I've been able to link FreeImage statically on several Visual studio versions. Here I describe how I do this usually.

With FreeImage, by default, we have 8 options to link it to your app:

FreeImage - dynamic link (you will need dll).

FreeImageLib - static link.

Each of these can be built with "Debug" or with "Release" configurations and for Win32 or Win64 platforms.

So, assume that we need ( Static && Win32 && Debug ) and ( Static && Win32 && Release ) variants for our app. Also in our app we use Dynamic Runtime Library (by default, FreeImage set up for static for some reason)
How we usually got it:

- Download and unpack fresh version (or at least clean up old distib)
- Open `FreeImage.2008.sln` select ALL of 10 projects with Shift+click. Then in "Project(s) Properties / C++ / Code generation" we choose /MDd for "Debug" configuration and /MD for "Release".
- Then we go to "Menu / Build / Batch build", select:

  `FreeImageLib | Debug   | Win32`

  `FreeImageLib | Release | Win32`

and press "Build".

- Wait for choosen configurations built. All what we need will be copied in `FreeImage\Dist` folder
- in `FreeImage\Dist` folder check files:
  `delete.me`
  `FreeImage.h`
  `FreeImage.lib`
  `FreeImaged.lib`
  Check creation date and time. It must be fresh baked and hot. If they not, copy them from `FreeImage\Source\FreeImageLib\Debug` and `FreeImage\Source\FreeImageLib\Release`.
- In main applicaion add to include and lib `FreeImage\Dist` and link `FreeImaged.lib` to Debug configurations and `FreeImage.lib` to Releases.
- Include in source file:

  `#define  FREEIMAGE_LIB`

  `#include "FreeImage.h"`
- Try to call
  `FreeImage_Initialise();`
  `FreeImage_DeInitialise();`
- It should work

Happy coding!

Comment: Worked for me. Amongst the others (Magick++, OIIO), FreeImage is the easiest to get going with.