# Linking FreeImage VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, lnk2019, freeimage

Have been trying to link FreeImage to with Visual Studio Express 2013 and getting little stuck, have followed
[Building & Linking FreeImage with Visual Studio Express 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085997/building-linking-freeimage-with-visual-studio-express-2013)
and problem with having to include  seems to been fixed with update FreeImage.

Have downloaded and extracted Lib, .h, and DLL and linked in VS but still getting LNK2019.

In solution folder is simple folders named lib + inc and linked in options

C/C++ - Additional Include Directories - .\inc

linker - general - additional lib directories - .\lib

and the DLL is in the folder with the .exe

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Rick

Comment: What exactly is your problem you are facing or question?

Comment: Sorry wasnt that clear, getting LNK2019 unresolved externals for each call using Freeimage

Comment: Did you add `.lib` file to linker options? Here are the [instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186300/linking-freeimage-as-a-static-library-in-vs2010/16193893#16193893)

Comment: I created folder called lib which I linked directly to

Answer (score 0):

Ok found solution, well work around. Rather than linking the lib's etc myself by using NuGet was able to get FreeImage up and running. If only all things could have such a simple answer.

Any further details about how to get it working by linking the headers and lib etc would still be great help for future lib's i may need to link.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/freeimage/

Comment: That link's package version seems outdated (3.16.0). According to [Official Page](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), it says that latest version is 3.17.0.